# python regex dash

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match the following line in python however this line is not working.

Example text is:

```
usr/local/java/latest/bin/java-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/foobarcode/conf/
```

Example python:

```
re.match(r"/usr/local/java/latest/bin/java[-]Djava[.]util[.]logging[.]config[.]file[=]/usr/local/tomcat/(\.*)/conf/\.*", pidInfo)
```

Any help that can be provided will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `\.*` would match a literal `.` 0 or more times.

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary, your edit breaks the Python syntax. If the long lines are a problem for you, use the `\` line continuation char, but don't break the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you escape the `.`. That makes it a literal period. You want to leave it unescaped so that it becomes the wildcard:

```
re.match(r"/usr/local/java/latest/bin/java-Djava[.]util[.]logging[.]config[.]file=/usr/local/tomcat/(.*)/conf/.*", pidInfo)
```

Also, your input example does not contain the leading `/`, but that might be a copy-paste mistake. (And note that there is no need to escape `=` and `-`).

Comment: D0h - the issue is it appears off-screen the area you're referring to!

Comment: @JonClements I prefer the scrollbar to the random line-breaks in how the question is rendered ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the fixed version of what you're trying to do:

```
>>> s = '/usr/local/java/latest/bin/java-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/foobarcode/conf/'
>>> re.match(r'/usr/local/java/latest/bin/java-Djava\.util\.logging\.config\.file=/usr/local/tomcat/(.*)/conf/.*', s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1004a0648>
```

Issues:

1. You do not need to escape the `.` as a wildcard
2. You do need to (elegantly) escape `\.` when used as dots in filename (`[.]` works just fine, just less elegant IMO)
3. Missing root `/` in filename
4. `-` and `=` chars do not need escaping

Comment: My version, I like it better, but yeah `[.]` works as well :)

Comment: Yeah, but you say it like `\.` is **the** way to go, although it is really nothing but a matter of taste. I find the character class escape technique much more readable in many cases.

Comment: I tried running the regex you created and it still won't match unless I change the "-" to a ".+"  Other than that it seems to work flawlessly.